# Is Deidara a boy or a girl?

Tags: naruto

In the manga his gender is sometimes confused due to the Japanese language's sparse use of third person pronouns, which forces translators to use their own ideas of Deidara's gender to make sentences flow smoothly. This has caused a lot of confusion, since both "he" and "she" are used to refer to Deidara. However, Deidara speaks of "himself" using **male** pronouns and has been given a very deep, male voice in the anime.

Someone asked me this and it got me pretty confused. In the Naruto Wiki page it says that Deidara was a boy, but I wasn't sure.

http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Deidara

Answer (score 8):

Deidara is a man. He looks like a man, uses pronouns and a way of speaking that is pretty much exclusive to men, and has male voice actors in English and Japanese. While it's not uncommon for women to voice male characters who are young/immature, it is rare for a man to voice a female character.

There is no reason to think Deidara is a girl, and overwhelming evidence to suggest he is a man.

Comment: Okay good. I knew he was a guy but when that person asked me that question it just got me all confused. And also it is not rare for a man to voice a female character. I have seen that happen a lot of times, mostly in American cartoons.

Comment: just remember when he used C0, he naked and don't have a breast :)